# Percona MySQL 5.5 Unique key is duplicated

Tags: mysql, php, percona, duplication

I'm totally out from ideas, so maybe somebody else could answer my question.
We have a MySQL 5.5 server from Percona with high traffic. The application is in PHP and writes always to master. We have at the same time 4 slaves from which we only read. Basically it is a standard master-slave configuration. 
Last week happened that the replication was broken on all slaves, so I checked, what is wrong with the database. 
What I found out is basically my question, how can this happen:
The unique key column (not the primary key) from one of the tables has the same value in 2 rows. I tried to find out if this happened more then one time, but not. It is happened only one time, but I would understand why or how can this happen.
For better understanding here are some real data from our database:

```
show create table registeredUsers;
| registeredUsers | CREATE TABLE `registeredUsers` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `client` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `osVersion` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `deviceGroup` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `registrationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastAction` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cultureLanguage` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `cultureRegion` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `cultureCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'de-de',
  `lastPush` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pushToken` mediumtext,
  `permaToken` varchar(74) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accessCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `provider` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `providerTld` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `environment` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `udidMd5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `development` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId_2` (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `permaAccessToken_2` (`permaToken`),
  KEY `client` (`client`),
  KEY `lastAction` (`lastAction`),
  KEY `deviceGroup` (`deviceGroup`),
  KEY `osVersion` (`osVersion`),
  KEY `cultureCode` (`cultureCode`),
  KEY `udidMd5` (`udidMd5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38466378 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

The problematic column is the userId, which is unique.
Here is a query which shows that we have 2 rows with the same value:

```
mysql> select userId, count(userId) as ct from registeredUsers group by userId having ct;
+----------------------------------+----+
| userId                           | ct |
+----------------------------------+----+
| 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |  2 |
+----------------------------------+----+
1 row in set (3.53 sec)
```

I even cannot reproduce so it would be really cool if somebody has an explanation for this situation.

Thank you in advance,
Tamas

**UPDATE**
As requested here is the result for the collation:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM registeredUsers;
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field            | Type                | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id               | bigint(20) unsigned | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| userId           | varchar(32)         | utf8_general_ci | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| client           | varchar(200)        | utf8_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| osVersion        | varchar(10)         | utf8_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| deviceGroup      | varchar(50)         | utf8_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| registrationDate | datetime            | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| lastAction       | datetime            | NULL            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| cultureLanguage  | varchar(2)          | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| cultureRegion    | varchar(2)          | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| cultureCode      | varchar(5)          | utf8_general_ci | NO   | MUL | de-de   |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| lastPush         | datetime            | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| pushToken        | mediumtext          | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| permaToken       | varchar(74)         | utf8_general_ci | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| accessCount      | int(11)             | NULL            | NO   |     | 0       |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| access           | varchar(1)          | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | 1       |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| provider         | varchar(255)        | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| providerTld      | varchar(5)          | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| environment      | tinyint(1)          | NULL            | YES  |     | 0       |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| udidMd5          | varchar(32)         | utf8_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| development      | tinyint(1)          | NULL            | YES  |     | 0       |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM registeredUsers WHERE userid = '748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9' ORDER BY id DESC ;
+----------+
| id       |
+----------+
| 38245456 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select userId from registeredUsers where id in (38245456, 38245457);
+----------------------------------+
| userId                           |
+----------------------------------+
| 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |
| 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |
+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, userId from registeredUsers where id in (38245456, 38245457);
+----------+----------------------------------+
| id       | userId                           |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| 38245456 | 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |
| 38245457 | 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |
+----------+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, userId from registeredUsers where userId = '748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9';
+----------+----------------------------------+
| id       | userId                           |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| 38245456 | 748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9 |
+----------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 3**
To be sure, that the two strings are identical, here is a query which gives back all 2 rows. (Thanks to sugestion for it)

```
SELECT id FROM registeredUsers WHERE userid >= '748ec561dbc733452bfd697076787ef9' LIMIT 2;
+----------+
| id       |
+----------+
| 38245456 |
| 38245457 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like you might have hit a bug logged against Percona Server 5.5:
[Concurrent duplicate inserts can violate a unique key constraint in InnoDB tables](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1322559).

There is no fix and no reproducible test case for this bug yet. It has only been observed in a production environment.

The pattern described is:

1. INSERT a value into a column with a unique constraint.
2. DELETE that row.
3. Two concurrent sessions INSERT new rows that have the same value as in the deleted row.
4. Both sessions commit, and both of their INSERTs succeed.

The root cause might be related to unfinished purging of the deleted row. In InnoDB, deleting an entry from an index is a multi-step process. First, the entry is "delete-marked" which leaves the entry in the index so as to postpone the physical removal from the index. Then later, the purge thread performs the final removal, which may include some rebalancing of the B-tree.

If you try to insert the same value as one which is delete-marked, it simply removes its delete mark, and associates the value with the new row you insert.

Based on the bug report, it seems that while the deleted entry is merely delete-marked, but not yet purged, two concurrent sessions can insert the same value. This probably happens all the time on non-unique indexes, and it's no problem. But of course this is a problem if the index is a unique index.

Sorry, there's no resolution to this bug yet. I encourage you to log into launchpad and register that this bug affects you. If you can post additional information about how the bug occurs in your environment, that would be helpful too. Best of all is if you can help create a reproducible test case!

Also, this *might* be related to a bug against stock MySQL: [Bug #69979 columns with unique key gets intermittent duplicate values!](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69979) although some details are different. That MySQL bug was closed as "not a bug" because the developers apparently concluded that in InnoDB's MVCC architecture, it's acceptable for some conflicts to occur and produce invalid results based on race conditions. IMHO, this should earn them a resounding "WTF?!"